# Gravity Forms - Prevent Multiple Form Entries Same User ID with Same Field Value

Tags: php, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a form where users will submit a timecard.

- All entries to this form will be from users who are logged in (this part I have figured out).
- Users will enter their name, the amount of hours, and select the date for the timecard (week ending).
- **The issue I'm encountering** is how to limit the form so that each user can only submit the form once for each week ending (the date field).
- Every user should be able to submit a form for the same date, but only once per user.
- I'm not limiting per time period, because perhaps they forgot a timecard for last week and and so they should be able to enter two form submissions back to back, one for this week and one for last week, but only one form submission per user, per date selected in the date field.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-submissions/

Gravity Perks is a great addon to gravity forms that does a lot of cool things. This particular add on would solve this problem - plus they have great support.

I found this on github - I gave it a try and it didn't break my site:

https://github.com/uamv/gravityforms-custom-entry-limit

Not sure if that means per user though - but maybe worth giving a try. Not really clear by the documentation. The first perks will definitely solve this problem though.

Comment: Hey, Doug - thanks for the reply. I tried this, but my experience was that it was for all users. Thank you again though!

Answer (score 0):

For most fields in a Gravity Forms form it is possible to tick the No Duplicates field. If you for example let the people filling out your form also enter their e-mail address (that's unique for a person most of the time) and set that field to no duplicates than you might get the result you want.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/common-field-settings/#no-duplicates

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Unfortunately I found that this limited all duplicates (so a user could only submit once ever, not per week) or that once someone submitted a timecard for the week, no one else could (as all other timecards showed as duplicates).